# UIStepper issue in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uistepper

I have a `UIStepper` in every cell to increment/decrement a label near it.

```
class VariantsNewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: QuantityProtocol?

    @IBAction func addItemsValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {

        delegate?.addQuantity(cell: self)

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var addItems: UIStepper!

    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel!

}
```

In `UIViewController`:

```
func addQuantity(cell: VariantsNewCell) {

    let newQuery = (drinksConfirmView[thisIndex![1]] as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0,1), with: "\(Int(cell.addItems.value))")

    drinksConfirmView[thisIndex![1]] = newQuery

                        self.tableVariantsQuantityView.reloadRows(at: [thisIndex!], with: .fade)

}
```

The problem is that it won't update each row correctly. It seems to work the first time, but then after I tap again, it goes up the number it was before tapping the second cell.

I tap row 0 and have 1x -> 2x
I tap again in row 0 and I get the same value. I set a breakpoint and it reloads the row.

If I do this with the same row, it partially works fine, but you have to tap two times to get an increment.

If I then decide to tap on row 4, I get an increment of the last value I had previously. So if I end with 5x in row 0, I get 5x in row 4 no matter what value.

Same thing happens, as I have 5x in row 4, I tap row 3 and get 6x.

When I try to decrement, I have to tap twice and it alternates between (I assume it stores a value for the `stepper`) the value stored and the value expected.

It gets even worse when you try to add more than 10x, it starts giving values of 110x, 132x, weird values that seem to have a pattern but it's definitely not what I want.

My guess is to use `prepareForReuse()`

Comment: What is `thisIndex!` and `thisIndex![1]`?

Comment: That's how I get the index in the `tableview`. It an `IndexPath` and I use that to get the right data from each section/row